# how to fix this Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 2 Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm solving a hacker rank challenges and i'm stuck with an error

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 2 
>   Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator.

kindly suggest the chnages

I have tried writing this query

```
SELECT CEILING((AVG(Salary))-(AVG(REPLACE(Salary,0,'')))) FROM EMPLOYEES
```

2061

Comment: I would not let you calculate my salary!

Comment: BTW, what does `REPLACE(Salary, 0, '')` is supposed to do? Why should a salary of  `10101` become `111`?

Comment: Why are you storing salary as a `varchar` and not as a numerical data type? If you add 2 people's salaries together (let's say they both get paid `25000`) are you expecting `2500025000` (`'25000'+'25000' = '2500025000' != 50000`)? That's a very nice wage package. :D

Comment: See my answer and replace value with column Salary.

Comment: since it's some sort of 'challenge'.  I'd speculate that the design has been given as some sort of exercise to see if it can be solved with 'hacks' - is just a theory.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "true" answer here is to fix your data type. You can so by using the `ALTER` syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.EMPLOYEES ALTER COLUMN Salary decimal(18,2); --Assumed dbo schema
```

You may want to use a different datatype to `decimal(18,2)`, but that gives you the basic syntax.

Then a simple expression like `AVG(Salary)` won't generate an error about `Salary` being the wrong datatype for the operator.

Comment: We don't know if the column is varchar. `SELECT REPLACE(1234.56, 0, '')` works as-is on the decimal(6,2).

Answer (score 0):

Your Salary column is varchar, should be a numeric type.

```
SELECT CEILING((AVG(CAST (Salary AS DECIMAL (10,2))))-(AVG(CAST (Salary AS DECIMAL (10,2))))) FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger, copy paste issue.  ;)

Comment: It is not necessarily varchar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT CEILING((AVG(CAST('2061' as Int)))-(AVG(CAST('2061' as Int)))) FROM EMPLOYEES
```